# Querying for CLOB attribute in JPA

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I want to search for a value of the datatype CLOB in the database. The attribute in the entity looks as follows:

```
@Column(name = "FILE_NAME")
@Convert(converter = CryptoConverter.class)
@Lob 
private String fileName;
```

Unfortunately I am not able to query like this:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT o FROM OracleDok o WHERE o.fileName = :fileName", OracleDok.class);
query.setParameter("fileName", hanaDok.getFileName());
```

This will lead to the following exception:

> Inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

A native query would work - but the value is encrypted so I cannot use the filtervalue to match it against the value in the database because I can't crypt it manually with the key the databaseentry was encrypted.

How can I achieve this? Is there any way to set a parameter correctly?

Comment: Did you tried to setParameter as byte[] ?

Comment: setting it to byte[] doesn't work eiterh

Comment: look at this - [Large objects (LOBs) are not supported in comparison conditions.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions002.htm)